# Is it possible to transfer data from an offline website to an online database?

Tags: html, database, web, xampp, offline

For example, i'am using xampp. I want to make my web application to work offline whenever the internet goes down. Is it possible to get connected to an online database. What can u suggest is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing your specifics it quite hard to tell, but - generally speaking - this is definitely possible.

It's hard to achieve with the 'classic' round-trip HTTP website, hence I will assume that we are working with a SPA (single page application) and some kind of AJAX data connection. You could - for example - check your connection regularly and if it fails fall-back to some kind of local storage (HTML5 Local Storage). When the connection is back on you can push the data stored locally to your online database.

**But**, easy as it sounds, this can get extremely complicated. You'll have to take care of a lot of things and there will be lots of intricate details - depending on your domain.

Comment: I agree , is there any other way like is there a tool that converts php made website to a local application (maybe converted to another language).